# text slide on rollover

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-slide-effects

I have rollover thumbs that fade on my page but id like the text to slide into place instead of fading on but with a transparent colored bar under the text.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("img.b").hover(
function() {
$(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "70");
},
function() {
$(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, "100");
```

the way it operates now

http://toddheymandirector.com/REEL/

how id like it to operate

http://toddheymandirector.com/slide.html

Comment: I think you're talking about jQuery here, so I've tagged your question with that. If I'm wrong, please retag it with the framework this is using.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it a little like this: http://jsfiddle.net/xze3g/2/

EDIT: added opacity for IE

Comment: thanks thats great- there are two other elements though - there is the horizontal bar that goes behind the text as well as the change in color to the thumbnail

Comment: drawrdesign you rock.. so the last thing is the thumbnail itself changes..  original http://toddheymandirector.com/images/thumbs_jsh/nike.png rollover http://toddheymandirector.com/images/thumbs_jsh/nike_hot2.png

Comment: You don't have to change the thumbnail, just the opacity. Saves browser load time, and is faster :)

Comment: almost there the only prob is the opacity doesn't quite do it - theres an effect on the look and with a grey BG it just gets darker - thoughts  http://toddheymandirector.com/textslide.html

Comment: see how it looks here..its a yellowish cast i added in photoshop - something I can do in css?  http://toddheymandirector.com/images/thumbs_jsh/nike_hot2.png